# IOS: add a device in provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, device

I don't understand why if I open a project in xcode I can use my device with debug; and if I open another project I don't see it in debug and I can't use it...why??? in the same mac; naturally I add device in provisioning portal and I update provisioning in organizer.

Comment: Do you have the developer identity set for your new project?

Comment: See "Assigning Provisioning Profiles to Build Configurations" at : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is either the provisioning profile that mydogisbox [suggests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG7) or perhaps the device doesn't meet the minimum iOS Application Target settings. What is your hardware and what iOS version is it running? What do the new project's iOS Application Target settings require?

Answer (score 0):

Extending mydogisbox comment:
Do you have the developer identity set for your new project?

-- go to your project file

-- go to Build Settings Tab

-- search for "Code Signing"

-- U will see "Code Signing Identity" drop down

-- In the debug cell, make sure that you have your iPhone Developer provisioning profile.